# Hot Deploy EAR – (Netbeans 8.0.2 / Wildfly 9.0.1 / Maven 3.3.3)

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, deployment, jboss

Is there a procedure for hot deploying an ear file on Wildfly using Netbeans (8.0.2)? My current build process (one command)

```
mvn clean package wildfly:deploy
```

is killing me (4/5 builds/cigarettes per hour, 3 mins a build).

I've searched and searched the web and heard people talking about [3 millisecond deployments](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/maven_3_milliseconds_deployment_with) (which I can only dream of), hot deployments “*out of the box*” using Netbeans (`compile on save`) and adding `auto-deploy-exploded="true"` to the deployment-scanner in the wildfly configuration file.

But I still haven't got it. My build sends my deployment to the wildfly `standalone/tmp` folder. Not to `standalone/deployment` where I reckon the  deployment-scanner is looking.

What's a common setup people are employing to perform builds in Netbeans/Maven/Wildfly?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decided to give [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/) a try. Had some issues using it with **Wildfly 9.0.1.Final** (maybe it's not fully supported just yet), so reverted back to **Wildfly 8.2.1.Final**. Works a treat. I can now change my XHTML files, CSS files, Java code (in WAR & EJB Modules of EAR) and my changes are reflected by a simple Browser refesh. I guess it's goodbye to multiple builds and wasted time.